# php weird encoding behavior using strtolower('Fötus');

Tags: php, character-encoding

there seems to be some weird encoding issue when I run:

```
echo strtolower('Fötus');
```

I get `f�tus`

Why is ö even touched? (It is already lowercase)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**mb_strtolower()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) function as like below

```
echo mb_strtolower('Fötus');
// Output is fötus
```